# A typo on page 42 of Robinson's book on group theory.

Tags: group-theory, notation, wreath-product

There's a typo on page 42 of Robinson's,  *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*, *ISBN 987-1-4612-6442-9*.

Here's a picture:

[image]

It reads as follows:

> If $H$ and $K$ are permutation groups on finite sets $X$ and $Y$, show that the order of $\color{red}H\quad \color{red}K$ is $\lvert H\rvert^{\lvert Y\rvert}\lvert K\rvert$.

The typo is the gap between the red $H$ and $K$.

---

Based on the context, I believe it should be $\color{red}{H\wr K}$. In previous instances of the Wreath product in the book, the symbol $\wr$ is slanted backward a bit, so it takes up about the same amount of space as the gap in question; besides, the result seems to match [the properties of the Wreath product listed on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product).

> Is this correct?

Please help :)

Comment: I believe that is correct, but I'm not sufficiently versed in wreath products to be certain.

Comment: Well, not quite. $H\wr K$ is the unrestricted standard wreath product, which would have order $|H|^{|K|}|K|$. This would be what I would normally represent as $H\wr_Y K$, indicating the set on which $K$ acts. (Though Robinson seems to use $\sim$ rather than $\wr$ for some reason...)

Comment: But here $H$ and $K$ are actually permutation groups, not abstract groups, so there  is no question about what set they are acting on. I first encountered wreath product (in Marshall Hall's book) as being defined specifically for permutation groups, and learnt later that the regular action was the default for abstract groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $K$ acts on a set $\Omega$, the (unrestricted) wreath product $H\wr_{\Omega}K$ is the semidirect product of $\prod_{\omega\in\Omega}H$ by $K$, letting $K$ act on the product by permuting the coordinates according to its action. When no set is specified, $H\wr K$ is usually considered to be the (unrestricted) regular wreath product with $K$ acting on itself by translation (depending on how you write your wreath products, it can be the left or the right action...). Rotman uses $\wr_r$  to denote the regular wreath product.

(The restricted wreath product uses the restricted direct product instead, i.e. the subgroup of the cartesian product of almost null elements; Hanna Neumann's book uses $H\mathop{\mathrm{Wr}}_{\Omega}K$ for the unrestricted product, and $H\mathop{\mathrm{wr}}_{\Omega}K$ for the restricted one.)

In the case at hand, it is clear that Robinson means $H\wr_Y K$, given the cardinality.